# Java regex String.matches working inconsistently

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex which checks if a string is a number. The format's thousand separator is a white space, decimal separator is a dot. After-decimal part is optional.

The issue is that at some point String.matches() function stops working as expected. What worked before, does not work anymore.

For example, JUnit code:

```
import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class RegExTest {

    @Test
    public void testThousandSeperatorRegex()
    {
        String regEx = "([0-9]{1,3}( [0-9]{3})*(\\.[0-9]+)?|\\.[0-9]+)";
        Assert.assertEquals(true, "1".matches(regEx));
        Assert.assertEquals(true, "10".matches(regEx));
        Assert.assertEquals(true, "100".matches(regEx));
        Assert.assertEquals(true, "1 000".matches(regEx));
        Assert.assertEquals(true, "10 000".matches(regEx));
        Assert.assertEquals(true, "100 000".matches(regEx));
        Assert.assertEquals(true, "1 000 000".matches(regEx));
        Assert.assertEquals(true, "10 000 000".matches(regEx));
        Assert.assertEquals(false, "10000.56".matches(regEx));
        Assert.assertEquals(true, "8 734".matches(regEx));
    }
}
```

The last line with "8 734" fails. When I replace it with "1 000" it continues to fail. Eventually, the same code at the same run passes in the 4th line of assertions, but fails in the last (the new code is saved!). 
But there are times when everything starts working just as expected until.. start failing again. So I suppose that it will be hard to reproduce my issue. Maybe there are something else that I'm doing wrong which I haven't noticed and thus described, but I tried to make it as plain as possible.
This one confuses me a lot. Does String.matches() has a memory or what?

Could there be something wrong with the regular expression? I'm skipping `^$` as String.matches works on whole string anyway. I have tried java.util.regex and jregex packages, the issue persisted.

I'm using JDK 6u31.

Any ideas appreciated.

UPD: ok, after posting this Q the code started to work and hasn't fail so far. Maybe it was something with me, but this has bothered me since last week and I have been able to replicate it again and again. I will continue with my piece of code and if it will continue to work I will close this issue. Also I will try to determine what exactly caused the problem.
Meanwhile, if there are someone out there who has encountered the same issue, please share your knowledge. Otherwise, this looks like an issue that can be solved by knowledge, not by debugging. 
To defend myself from stupidity I can say I have been programming for many years and this is the 1st ever post in forums :). Until now I was able to solve my problems with debugging, reading docs and searching forums of other Qs.

Comment: Works for me in JDK 6u19

Comment: Can you post the actual class calling those JUnit tests?

Comment: Are you sure you're not running an old compiled class?

Comment: @Michael, yes I'm sure. I was suspecting it too. And I double saved it as Netbeans IDE saves the file before running too.

Comment: this is overly complicated, why not just replace all the `whitespace` with nothing and the test against `\d*\.?\d*`

Comment: It's something with the way you're running it, not an issue with Java. `"8 734".matches(regEx)` *will* print true, try it [here](http://ideone.com/O58To) and on your own machine.

Comment: What happens if you compile the regex and call `matches()` on the Pattern object instead of on the String?  Or if you get rid of the `(\\.[0-9]+)?|\\.[0-9]+` part?

Comment: (Tangentially related) I'd like to add plugs for `assertTrue()`, `assertFalse()`, and `NumberFormat`.

Comment: @Jarrod, it causes other issues that has to do with my program/context, so, I can't choose this solution.

Comment: @Alan Moore, I had already tried Pattern object, jregex library and also simplifying regex by removing 2nd part, but it didn't help me to determine what's the issue.

Comment: @Mark, thanks, will keep in mind. NumberFormat is not applicable here though.

Comment: @Bart, yes it has to do something with my environment as I posted that sometimes it works, sometimes not.

Comment: Did you try wrapping the first part (possibility) in parantheses: `(([0-9]{1,3}( [0-9]{3})*(\\.[0-9]+)?)|\\.[0-9]+)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so far I haven't encountered this issue anymore.

For other who happen to meet this one someday, I can only suggest to clean up the environment that you are working in. This has to do something with corrupted JVM or computer's memory state.

Thanks everyone for their contribution.

Answer (score 0):

BTW: Try to use pre-compiled pattern `Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regEx)` and single matcher for all assertions `assertTrue(p.matcher("1 000 000").matches())`. String's matches method compiles regex pattern every time you call it