# String.matches("(\\w)\\1") giving inconsistent results after certain execution attempts on string with length more than 100

Tags: java, regex, string

**Problem Statement :** When I used `String.matches("(\\w)\\1")` in my code.

It's giving inconsistent results after certain execution attempts on string with length more than 100

**Steps to Replicate this issue :**

Create java class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReducedString {

    static String super_reduced_string(String s){
        boolean isStringFinished = false;
        String newString = "";
        while(!isStringFinished) {
            newString = s.replaceAll("(\\w)\\1","");
            s = newString;
            if(!s.matches("(\\w)\\1")){
                isStringFinished = true;
            }
        }
        if(newString.length() == 0 )
            newString = "Empty String";
        return newString;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = in.next();
        String result = super_reduced_string(s);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Please run it and provide below string as input:

> oagciicgaoyjmahhamjymmwjnnjwmmvpxhpphxpvlikappakilyygvkkvgyymlpfddfplmhiodvvdoihfxpkggkpxfuevvuuvveu

Basically code logic is trying to remove all adjacent similar
    characters and reducing input string so Expected out should be:
    "Empty String".  But will not get this result.

To get expected output I tried the workaround below with method `matchPattern()`:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReducedString {

    static String super_reduced_string(String s){
        boolean isStringFinished = false;
        String newString = "Empty String";
        while(!isStringFinished) {
            newString = s.replaceAll("(\\w)\\1","");
            s = newString;
            if(!matchPattern(s)){
                isStringFinished = true;
            }
        }
        if(newString.length() == 0 )
            newString = "Empty String";
        return newString;
    }

    static boolean matchPattern(String s) {
        boolean isStringFinished = false;

        for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length()-1;i++) {
            char c1 = s.charAt(i);
            char c2 = s.charAt(i+1);  
            if(c1==c2)
                return true;
        }
        return isStringFinished;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s = in.next();
        String result = super_reduced_string(s);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

If Anyone faced same issue , could you please tell me why builtin functions is giving such inconsistent results

Comment: I followed anser given in : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126347/java-regex-string-matches-working-inconsistently) still getting same issue.

Comment: In `ReducedString`, qhy don't you put the `if(!s.matches("(\\w)\\1"))` in the while condition?

Comment: Do you know that `String.matches()` (virtually) adds a `^` and  `$` around your mask, that is the **whole string must match** to return `true`...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto make that an answer, so I can +1 it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call `str.matches(regex)` is equivalent of `Pattern.matches(regex, str)`, which is equivalent of `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).matches()`.

And the `Matcher.matches()` method attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern.

See:

- [String.matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-)
- [Pattern.matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches-java.lang.String-java.lang.CharSequence-)
- [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html)

Comment: I tried : Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).matches() still same issue I faced.

Comment: Yeah. Try `Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str).find()`.

Comment: thanks I got the expected result with above code change. :)

Answer (score 1):

As [Usagi Miyamoto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4899193/usagi-miyamoto) said in the comments, the problem is that using `String.matches()` only matches the whole string.

Also, since you use the pattern a lot of times, compiling it before using it will speed up the process, making it faster. I made it working like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class ReducedString {
    static String super_reduced_string(String s){
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w)\\1"); // precompile pattern
        while(s.length() > 0 && !p.matcher(s).matches()){ 
        // check on the length to avoid matching the empty string
            s = p.matcher(s).replaceAll("");
        }
        if(s.length() == 0 ){
            s = "Empty String";
        }
        return s;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String result = super_reduced_string("oagciicgaoyjmahhamjymmwjnnjwmmvpxhpphxpvlikappakilyygvkkvgyymlpfddfplmhiodvvdoihfxpkggkpxfuevvuuvveu");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: [For me it worked](http://ideone.com/ExUowq), at least with the string given as example.